# ¿Es resta consecutiva de valores? duda

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bomba = 10000;

main ()
{
    int sedan = 60, camioneta = 120, transporte= 200;
    int a;
    int l;
    
    do{
        printf ("\n\n----Llenar SEDAN (80 LT) OPCION 1----\n" "----LLenar CAMIONETA (120 LT) OPCION 2----\n"  "----Llenar TRANSPORTE PUBLICO (200 LT)----" );
        printf ("\n\nIngresa el auto a llenar:\n");
        scanf("%d", &l);
        
        switch (l)
        {
            case 1: 
            
                a=bomba-sedan;
                printf("%d", a);
                break;
            
            case 2:
            
                a=bomba-camioneta;
                printf("%d", a);
                break;
            
            case 3:
            
                a=bomba-transporte;
                printf("%d", a);
                break;   
            
            default:
            puts("Algo fallo");
            break;
        }
    }while(l!=3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Buenas tardes disculpen la molestia, estoy haciendo esta pequeña simulación de un bomba de gasolina que  esta llenando autos (cada auto con distinto valor),hay 3 case porque son tres autos que se abastecerán de la bomba de gas.
Por ejemplo elijes la opción 1 (sedan) se le restara 60 a 10000 (bomba) y hace el printf del resultado de "bomba"

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo hacer que el resultado de una operación u opción anterior (resta) se guarde o reemplace el valor original de bomba, haciendo así la ilusión de que se esta vaciando la bomba de gasolina por cada auto que llena (por  cada opción que oprimes)? ¿hay alguna teoría especifica que manejar para lograr esto?

Comment: `bomba = bomba - sedan`? No se si entendi bien tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Es super sencillo, lo importante es saber que hace `a-=b` ,básicamente aquí esta diciendo que le va a restar a tu variable `a` el valor de la derecha `b` y el igual significa que ese resultado se lo va a asignar a la variable de la izquierda `a` o si se te hace mas fácil de la siguiente forma `a=a-b`, te dejo tu código corregido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bomba = 10000;

main ()
{
    int sedan = 60, camioneta = 120, transporte= 200;
    int l;
    
    do{
        printf ("\n\n----Llenar SEDAN (60 LT) OPCION 1----\n" "----LLenar CAMIONETA (120 LT) OPCION 2----\n"  "----Llenar TRANSPORTE PUBLICO (200 LT)----" );
        printf ("\n\nIngresa el auto a llenar:\n");
        scanf("%d", &l);
        
        switch (l)
        {
            case 1: 
            
                bomba-=sedan;//bomba=bomba-sedan;
                printf("%d", bomba);
                break;
            
            case 2:
            
                bomba-=camioneta;//bomba=bomba-camioneta;
                printf("%d", bomba);
                break;
            
            case 3:
            
                bomba-=transporte;//bomba=bomba-transporte;
                printf("%d", bomba);
                break;   
            
            default:
            puts("Algo fallo");
            break;
        }
    }while(l!=3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: JAJAJAJA si soy tonto, estaba tratando los valores "bomba" y "a" como  si fueran dos cosas distintas. Es que me vi muchos videos y me quedo en la cabeza que tenia que alojar a  bomba en una variable distinta, por eso me salía un resultado estático sin cambios. Gracias estoy aprendiendo :3

Comment: Hahaha, no te preocupes, así empezamos todos.

Comment: @JaimeJonathanOrtizVelazco Los comentarios son con `//` no con `#`.

Comment: @Pablochaches hahaha, perdón, se tantos lenguajes que se me olvidan algunas sintaxis, ahorita lo cambio.